# Error when trying to get data from UserDefaults when it is empty

Tags: ios, swift, decode

I have this piece of code

```
let storedObject: Data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedHighScoreArray") as! Data
highScores = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([HighScore].self, from: storedObject)
```

Whenever it runs (and UserDefaults is empty) I get the following error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x10cfca0b8) to 'NSData' (0x10cfc75e8).
>   2019-05-13 16:21:55.225691+0200 BrainTrainerSwift[77393:4089984] Could not cast value of type '__NSCFArray' (0x10cfca0b8) to 'NSData' (0x10cfc75e8).

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't force cast if you aren't sure you got something saved for that key `object(forKey: "SavedHighScoreArray") as! Data`

seems you saved item in `UseDefaults` as an `Array`.

instead you can use a `guard let` or a `if let` so the app won't crash and you can manage the fallback

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SavedHighScoreArray") as? Data else { \\do something here for the fallback return  }
```